# Maximum principle for harmonic functions in unbounded domains

Tags: partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions

We demonstrated the weak maximum principle for harmonic functions
in bounded domains, proving it first considering the case u 
subharmonic, then approximating in this way:
choose $v(x)=x_1^2-M$ so that $\Delta v>0$ and $v<0$. 
Consider $u_{\epsilon}(x)=u(x)-\epsilon v(x)$ which is 
subharmonic so the principle holds, and taking the limit for
$\epsilon$ to 0 we obtain also the case u harmonic. This proof
depends essentially in the fact that the domain is bounded so we 
can choose a negative subarmonic $v$. Can we prove it also if 
the domain is not bounded? Of course if it is included in a strip
we can, but otherwise? So the question moves essentially to the existence
of a negative subharmonic function, which i couldn't find..

Answer (score 3):

The key term is the *Phragmén-Lindelöf principle*. The Wikipedia article talks only about the holomorphic functions. For subharmonic functions, see [these notes](http://www.dm.unibo.it/~arcozzi/subharmonic.pdf) (which seem to have origin in *Potential theory in the complex plane* by Ransford).